# Fix GRUB2 UEFI bootloader MBR after moving /boot mountpoint

Tags: boot, grub2

I have installed a debian based distribution on my drive. When I installed it, the / mountpoint was btrfs on a logical partition (/dev/sda7) with a mount point for /boot/efi on a fat32 logical partition (/dev/sda6).

I since wanted to use the savedefault feature of grub, which doesn't work on btrfs. So I booted up a live image with gparted and shrunk /boot/efi (/dev/sda6) added an ext4 partition /dev/sda8.

After that I adjusted `/etc/fstab` to use the new mount point and then followed the steps to repair grub.

1. mount the root file system `mkdir /tmp/rootfs && mount /dev/sda7 /tmp/rootfs`
2. mount the boot drive on the mounted file system `mount /dev/sda8 /tmp/rootfs/@/boot`
3. mount the efi partition `mount /dev/sda6 /tmp/rootfs/@/boot/efi`
4. mount sys `mount --bind /sys /tmp/rootfs/@/sys`
5. mount dev `mount --bind /dev /tmp/rootfs/@/dev`
6. mount proc `mount --bind /proc /tmp/rootfs/@/proc`
7. for good measure mount home `mount --bind /tmp/rootfs/@home /tmp/rootfs/@/home`
8. chroot into the rootfs `chroot /tmp/rootfs`
9. repair grub, apparently

To repair grub I used this command:

```bash
grub-install /dev/sda
```

And it says it's successful.
However when I then try to boot the system I get this error:

```
GRUB loading...
Welcome to GRUB!

error: file `/@/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod´ not found.
grub rescue>
```

Of course it can't find it there because it's not in /@/boot/ anymore. I think this is an error with the stage 1 bootloader in the MBR. How do I fix that? I use an msdos partition table.

I have also managed to boot the system from grub loaded from a USB drive with this command

```
set root=(hd1,msdos8)
linux /vmlinuz root=LABEL=LinuxRoot rootflags=subvol=@ quiet splash rw
initrd /initrd
boot
```

I have tried to reinstall grub from there as well, with no success. I have also tried this command, which also didn't work (says successful, but same error appears on reboot).

```bash
grub-install --bootloader-id=grub --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --no-nvram /dev/sda
```

Comment: I don’t understand the `@` symbol in your directory mounting points. Is this intentional? Could this have something to do with it?

Comment: @mpboden No, that's intentional because that's how btrfs subvolumes work.

Comment: Grub with UEFI is grub-efi-amd64 and normally in gpt partitioned drive. BIOS is grub-pc, if gpt you also need a bios_grub partition unformatted 1MB. The only reason for MBR (msdos) partitioning is if installing Windows in old BIOS boot mode.  Ubuntu will let you boot in UEFI mode from MBR, but UEFI suggests gpt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this properly by converting my msdos partition table to a gpt partition table. I did that by booting a live cd and running

```
gdisk /dev/sdX
w
```

Afterwards I had to reinstall the windows bootloader with a live medium and open a command prompt. Then run this sequence of commands to install a new bootloader to the EFI partition.

```
diskpart
  list disk
  select disk <volume for EFI partition>
  assign letter=O
  exit
bcdboot D:\Windows /s O
O:
cd EFI
mkdir Microsoft
cd Microsoft
bootrec /Fixboot
```

After that I just had to reinstall grub (target x86_64-efi). os-probe didn't detect windows, so I had to add it manually by adding it a new file `/etc/grub.d/42-windows` file like so

```
cat<<EOF
menuentry Windows {
    search --no-floppy --set=root --file '/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi'
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
EOF
```

After that run `sudo update-grub` and everything works fine.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix it by booting into the system as described above and then running

```bash
sudo apt install grub-pc-bin
sudo grub-install --bootloader-id=grub --target=i386-pc /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

After reboot, run:

```
sudo apt remove grub-pc-bin
sudo grub-install --bootloader-id=grub --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi /dev/sda # no-nvram is detected automatically at this point?
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

At this point everything is working as before. I just don't know why.